# Actionscript 2.0 XMLPath to access a <div> value in a XHTML file

Tags: flash, xpath, xhtml, actionscript-2, flash-cs5

I would appreciate any advice here. Based on what I have found on the web, I have tried the following  to try get what I need working.

I am using Actionscript 2.0 XPath to try and access a `<div>` value in an xhtml file, but I have this simple piece of Actionscript that I cannot get working:

```
=====================
stop();

import mx.xpath.XPathAPI;

var rssfeed_xml:XML = new XML();
rssfeed_xml.ignoreWhite = true;
rssfeed_xml.onLoad = function(success:Boolean) {
trace("onload...");
if (success) {
trace("success...");


var elementId:String = "title1";
var elementPath:String = "//div[@id'" + elementId + "']";
found_elements = XPathAPI.selectNodeList(rssfeed_xml.firstChild, elementPath);


if (found_elements.length == 1) {
  trace(found_elements[0]);
}


} else {
trace("error loading XML");
}
};
rssfeed_xml.load("test.xhtml");

=====================
```

My test.xhtml is simple, as such:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Landing</title>
</head>

<div id="mainArea">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="calloutContent">
            <div id="title">Search Our QA Database</div>
            <div id="callout1">text1</div>  
            <div id="callout2">text2</div>         
            <div id="callout3">text3</div>
        </div>
    <div id="heroContent">
        <div id="title1">text4</div>
        <div id="title2">text5</div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In my Actionscript, I am just trying to get the value of `<div id="title1">`, which is "text4".

The Actionscript code looks right, but I am not getting anything coming through on the line `trace(found_elements[0]);`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is coming from the path you have created.  This is your current path (with the variable inlined):

```
"//div[@id'title1']"
```

There are a couple of things wrong here:

- The XHTML is missing an opening `<body>` tag
- the `//` at the start does nothing. To wildcard a node you need to use the `*` symbol. This will then give you the first node depth. The get to the depth you require you will need to repeat this three more times.
- missing an `=` after the attribute name.

This path works to target your chosen div:

```
"/*/*/*/*/div[@id='title1']"
```

That path returns the complete node however, so to just extract the text you then request the `firstChild.nodeValue`:

```
trace(found_elements[0].firstChild.nodeValue);
```

The obvious problem here is that you have to know pretty much where your target node appears within the document.

Comment: Thanks shanethehat. The <body> tag was a oversite. And again, thanks for the path explanation. I will give that a go. The xhtml structure will not change, so I know exactly where the `<div>` that I need will be. I will give this a go and let you know how I get on. Thanks again, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Hi shanethehat. I just tried that, and still no joy.

I changed the main bit, so it now reads:

`var elementPath:String = "/*/*/*/*/div[@id='title1']";`
`found_elements = XPathAPI.selectNodeList(rssfeed_xml.firstChild, elementPath);`


`if (found_elements.length == 1) {`
  `trace(found_elements[0].firstChild.nodeValue);`
`}`

But still nothing coming out on the trace. Any ideas. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry shanethehat, but is this the best way of doing this, by using `selectNodeList`....is there a better way to get the exact `<div>` I want...maybe `selectSingleNode`...just wondering really...any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks again...

Comment: @Alan - Sorry, my mistake, by adding the body tag back in you need an extra depth: `"/*/*/*/*/*/div[@id='title1']"`.

Comment: You're welcome. If this is the correct answer you can mark it as such with the tick.